# "painful on the eyes" or "painful to the eyes"

Tags: prepositions

> The Goblet of Fire now shone more brightly than anything in the whole Hall, the sparkling bright, bluey-whiteness of the flames almost **painful on the eyes**.

I feel "*painful to the eyes*" might be correct too. I'm wondering if there is any difference between "*painful **on** the eyes*" and "*painful **to** the eyes*"? Or "*painful to the eyes*" is just plain wrong?

Comment: It's nearly always ***to*** rather than ***on***, but that doesn't make the less common version "incorrect". Also note that [***we're just as likely***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=painful+on+the+eyes%2Cpainful+to+the+eyes%2Cpainful+on+the+eye%2Cpainful+to+the+eye&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpainful%20to%20the%20eyes%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpainful%20to%20the%20eye%3B%2Cc0) to use singular ***eye*** rather than plural ***eyes***. Again, neither is more "correct" than the other, nor is there any *semantic* distinction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**on the eyes** can refer to the eyes as beholders, not as organs. You find it used in hardboiled detective novels to say that a woman is pretty and attractive:

> The dame was a tall glass of water and easy on the eyes.

Someone who is used to hearing **on** used in that manner might infer that there was some kind of *aesthetic*  discomfort when looking at the fire, not just a physical one.

But **on** can also have the basic meaning of "in its effect, respecting":

> This medication is easy on the stomach.
>
> This was his first offense, so the judge was not too hard on him, and sentenced him to 90 days plus time served.

But the object of **on** in either case is something that can be *burdened* in some way, literally or figuratively.

Comment: Thanks! "painful to the eyes" is not correct in any case?

Comment: Nothing wrong with "painful to the eyes".  If something is painful to the eyes, it hurts them.  Eye drops if they sting could be said to be a little painful to the eyes.

Comment: Does "painful to the eyes" denote the same meaning as ""painful on the eyes""?

Comment: The nuanced meaning is slightly different. Something that is **painful to** *causes* pain to the thing.   Something that is **painful on** is felt by the thing as pain.  When something is easy on the stomach, the stomach is not distressed by it. When something is harsh to the stomach, it affects the stomach with its harshness.

Answer (score 1):

At least in US English**, I think "Painful *to* the eyes" is correct. The example you offer, of flames *almost* painful to the eyes, is referring to real physical pain (why they said "almost"). The preposition I have always heard with "painful" is "to".
I think the use of "painful on" is slightly awkward. It sounds a little "off", but maybe not completely wrong. Probably the author is mixed up because of a different English expression: "easy on the eyes".

That is an idiom that playfully confuses something beautiful with something that comforts your eyes (sight organs). It is so common that when we read the phrase "painful on the eyes" we think, " 'easy-on-the-eyes'? ... well this must be the opposite". But strictly speaking, I think you are right; it should be "painful to the eyes".

** Other types of English *may* be different. I have no idea.